# OSMAnd Cannot Compile Need android-support-design.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Tags: android, osmdroid, point-of-interest, osmand

I am trying to get the OSMAnd project to compile from:

https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand

I am getting missing android-support-design.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\design\bin\android-support-design.jar'

Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

I am getting no resource found that matches given name in Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml and Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml

Below is few error messages out of many in those two files:

```
    [2015-08-26 19:17:27 - android-support-design] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    [2015-08-26 19:17:27 - android-support-design] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    [2015-08-26 19:17:27 - android-support-design] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
    [2015-08-26 19:17:27 - android-support-design] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:150: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2015-08-26 19:22:26 - OsmAnd] \Downloads\Osmand-master\Osmand-master\eclipse-compile\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
```

Update 1:
Compiles halfway and getting this error:

```
 [2015-08-26 19:54:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuItemView;
 [2015-08-26 19:54:40 - OsmAnd] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuItemView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps described here:

https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/GradleCommandLineBuildEnvironment

Comment: Beside posting the link, you could insert the most relevant part of the information you found at that link. This will help in case, in the future, that link won't be longer available.

Comment: @il_raffa that is true.  google is pulling the plug on most projects on code.google.com.